# Backbone model is destroyed even on service error

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-model

I'm trying to destroy a backbone model and it gets destroyed even on a service error.

```
View : 
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', function() {});

this.model.destroy({
   success : function(model) { 
       /* remove the li view */
   },
   error : function() {}

});
```

In above case model is removed from collection whether it is a success/error.

Suppose if this destroy callback fails the model should not be removed from the collection. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server to respond before removing the model from the collection:

```
View : 
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', function() {});

this.model.destroy({
   success : function(model) { 
       /* remove the li view */
   },
   error : function() {},
   wait:true

});
```

Comment: Do you want to remove a model from the collection after a certain timeout? or deal with request time out?

Comment: Try passing `timeout:<milliseconds>` at the options hash. I haven't tried it myself, but I think these properties are fed to jquery's ajax function (that accepts timeout:...)

Comment: I tried adding timeout it didn't work. I also overrode the sync within the model .. App.Models.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ urlRoot : '../SampleService/api/  sync: function(method, model, options) { options.timeout = 10000; }); even this didn't work.

Comment: mm... that's strange. You could also set a global timeout for your entire application, could you see if that thing works? (At least for the moment so we can figure out where the problem is exactly) `$.ajaxSetup({timeout:50000});`

Comment: @Protostome Thank you for your wonderful answer.. 1 for you.  but I want to romve the model only if response is positive means if it goes to success callback.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - Isn't it the default behavior?

Comment: @Protostome No weather My web service is working or not the model gets removed and removed from view. Please help. Can you for chat for same time.